# Is this a morphological error? or an instance of neologism?

Tags: morphology, neologisms

A learner's error of translation:

> Hand me the pincers. (for pliers)

Is this an error of morphology; or is it, as I think, a neologism, in that the learner substitutes a term he already knows for the correct word in the vocabulary.

Am I correct or totally wrong?

Comment: Context please! Link? Surrounding dialog? Where did you hear this?

Comment: And did you look up *pincers* and *pliers* just to check whether you were correct or not? If so, where; and what did you find?

Answer (score 5):

The mistake here is neither *morphological* nor *neologistic*; it is *lexical*.

*Morphology* denotes the changes of form of which a word is grammar required to undergo in order to make it agree with a specific context. *Me* for *I* when the word is used as indirect object is a *morphological* change; if the translator had written *Hand I the pincers* the error would be *morphological*.

*Neologism* is, literally, the process of building or inventing new words, but it is more often used to designate a word so invented. Sometimes the term is used in a neutral sense to describe the historic origin of a word: “*Oxygen* is a neologism created in 1777 by the French chemist Lavoisier from Greek *oxys* and French *gène*, itself derived from a Greek word." More often the term is used in a deprecating sense: “This term [*electrocution*], descriptive of the method of Inflicting the death penalty on convicted criminals in some of the states, is a vulgar neologism of hybrid origin, which should be discountenanced.” The translator has not invented a new word — both *pincers* and *pliers* have been around for a long time.

What the translator has done, you tell us, is simply chosen the wrong word from the English vocabulary or *lexicon*.

Answer (score 4):

It's nothing so complex as that. [Pincers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pincer_%28tool%29) are a different tool than [pliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliers). Either you are mistaken in your assessment of what the tool is, or the speaker is unaware of the difference.

Comment: Pincers and Pliers are two separate tools shaped differently but function in similar ways. The title of the tool was confused in translation in their sentence structure.

Comment: Who is 'their'? What was the full translation? The source?